# Regular and non-regular sets

Tags: math, theory, regular-language

I have to state whether the following are regular sets. These are my answers, I would like to know if I am correct and get additional input on my reasoning. Also, I want to rationalize these intuitively without using the pumping lemma, which I have been told is not too difficult for any of the following.

I only need to show the question at the bottom formally.

```
   a. {(a^n)(b^m) | n!=m} 
   b. {xcx | x is in {a,b}*}
   c. {xcy | x,y is in {a,b}*}
   d. {(a^n)(b^n+481) | n >= 0}
   e. {(a^n)(b^m) | n>=m and m<= 481}
   f. {(a^n)(b^m) | n>=m and m>= 481}
   h. {(a^n)(b^n)(c^n) | n>=0}


a. Not regular. This would imply that {(a^n)(b^n) | n>=0} is regular, which isn't true either by the closure properties for regular sets.
b. For both b and c, I don't think I am conceptualizing it correctly. Since x can be any arbitrary string of a's or b's, I would say that both parts b and c are not regular. But I don't think that this is correct.
c. See above.
d. Not regular. From the same reasoning from a. Adding a constant really means nothing since n is unbounded positively. 
e. Unsure.
f. Unsure.
h. Not regular from the same reasoning as a.
```

Finally I must *formally* prove that there is no infinite subset of {(a^n)(b^n) | n>=0} such that the subset is regular.

Can this be done in a simple way without the Pumping Lemma? Since I don't have a very good grasp on regular sets I haven't attempted this yet.

Comment: This question would be better off at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For (b) I think the intention is to require that the prefix is identical to the suffix (so not regular).  For (c), they can be different, which would make it regular.  I think you'll need the Pumping Lemma for the other cases & proof. (FYI, I fixed what I think is a typo for part (a) -- you had n for both exponents.)

Comment: @kajic, this is a specific area of CS theory, so I think it is still applicable here. Perhaps it would be more applicable on the theory subdomain, but it belongs here just as much as it belongs on math imo.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ 
I take back by comment about moving it to math, but I still think it would make more sense at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I can get on board with that.

Comment: Simple thing you need to think about where it required finite (bounded) information to process language of string or not --that also implies whether it is possible to draw FA.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some comments:

- For (a), I believe you're right, but you need to be careful how you justify why if that language is regular then { a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> | n in N } is regular.  Make sure you understand what closure properties you'd use.
- For (b), as a hint, use a homomorphism.  Can you delete the c?
- For (c), think about what this language means.  Is `aabaabc` in the language?  Is `caab` in the language?  Can you find a much more concise way of describing it, say, with a regular expression?
- For (d), you can prove it's not regular by using closure under concatenation and union.  Do you see how?
- For (e), try writing the language as { a<sup>n</sup> | n ≥ 0 } ∪ { a<sup>n</sup>b | n ≥ 1 } ∪ { a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>2</sup>} ∪ ... { a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>471</sup> | n ≥ 471 }.  Does that help?
- For (f), as a hint, it's not regular.  Do you see why, given the intuition from (e)?
- For (h), use the same technique as in (b).

Finally, for your last question, you can indeed use the pumping lemma here.  In the normal proof of the pumping lemma, you'd pick the string a<sup>p</sup>b<sup>p</sup>, where p is the pumping length.  You can use a similar trick, but you can't guarantee that a<sup>p</sup>b<sup>p</sup> is in the language.  However, can you show that a<sup>p+k</sup>b<sup>p+k</sup> must be in the language for some k ≥ 0?

Hope this helps!